# Install debian without gnome

Tags: debian, package-management

I would like to install debian with another desktop than Gnome. In this case I can't use tasksel but have to install every package with apt-get. What do I need to run debian with Windowmaker?

Comment: What about `apt-get install wmaker`?

Comment: I suppose I will also need an x-server and a graphical login page.

Comment: X should be automatically pulled in as dependency. A graphical login page (called display manager) is not necessary. If you want one you have to install it separately (e.g. gdm, slim, lightdm).

Comment: Install Debian minimal. Install a WM or X, then wmaker

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get install wmaker` will install windowmaker and all dependencies.

However, there are other optional window-maker related packages that you may also want to install.  To get a list of them, run:

`apt-cache search windowmaker`

then apt-get install the extra packages you want.

You'll probably also want a display manager.  gnome's gdm3 is the default, but there are others available including lightdm, kdm, xdm, and wdm. The last is "WINGs Display Manager - an xdm replacement with a WindowMaker look"

BTW, apt-get will, by default, install Recommends: as if they were Depends: - this is likely to bring in a whole bunch of gnome stuff that you don't want.  You can disable that by creating a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, and adding `APT { Install-Recommends "False";};`
 to it.

Also BTW, if you just want a Windowmaker/NextStep look and feel, you may find that one of XFCE4's themes is adequate for your needs.  My tastes have changed a bit since I last used WMaker but I still like the WMaker style window decorations.  Openbox is also a nice window manager that has some good NextStep-ish themes - I used to use it until I switched from gnome2 to xfce4 (when i gave up on gnome3's fallback mode ever being a viable replacement for gnome2)...xfce's  xfwm4 did most of the things i cared about from openbox and was less hassle to get working.  i'd got very bored of wasting time getting my desktop back to what it should be, and just wanted something working quick that didn't annoy me.